# Java multithreading concepts in Semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I created a **Semaphore**

```
Semaphore semaphore =  new Semaphore(1);
```

We have overloaded **aquire** methods like:

```
aquire()
aquire(int)
```

**Q1 :** For the current semaphore where there is only 1 permit, will the second method(`aquire(int)`) have any significance?

**Q2:** I am still a bit confused with

```
new Semaphore(int)
new Semaphore(int,true)
new Semaphore(int, false)
```

**Q3:** If I call `release()`, without calling `aquire()`, what happens to the number of permits, does that increase than what we have declared?

**Note : There are multiple threads which share the `Semaphore` Object .**

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Semaphore` starts out with a single permit and a single thread tries to acquire more than 1 permit, then that thread will block. Assuming no other thread will ever call the necessary number of `release`, then the thread will be blocked indefinitely.

The `boolean` argument to the [overloaded constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore-int-boolean-) indicates

> if this semaphore will guarantee first-in first-out granting of
>   permits under contention, else false

The number of permits you specify in the constructor is just an initial amount, not a limit.

Comment: Thanks for replying, there are multiple threads which share the `Semaphore` object

Comment: @SashiKant The number of permits you specify in the constructor is just an initial amount, not a limit.

Comment: up 1 for your comment, but I am still confused with *** Question 2 and 3 ***

Comment: @SashiKant Can you clarify what you don't understand? Multiple threads may invoke `acquire`. Setting the flag to `true` in the constructor will guarantee the order in which threads will receive the permits (FIFO). Since the initial number of permits isn't a limit, any number of threads can call `release` and the number of permits will keep increasing.

Answer (score 1):

> Q2: I am still a bit confused with

```
new Semaphore(int)          //same as new Semaphore(i, false);
new Semaphore(int,true)     //the Semaphore will be "fair".
new Semaphore(int, false)   //the semaphore will not be "fair".
```

The boolean flag controls whether or not the semaphore is *fair*.  "Fair" means that when more than one thread is blocked waiting to acquire permits, then the waiting threads will get to run in strict first-come first-served order.  The first thread to be blocked will be the first one to run, and so on.

When the Semaphore is *not* fair, then it may be implemented by an algorithm that potentially gives higher performance as compared to the fair algorithm on some computer architectures.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Hope there would had been an option to select multiple correct answer rather than selecting one :)